# MYSQL Workbench Primary Key not updating

Tags: mysql-workbench

Using MYSQL Workbench and MYSQL 8 community installed on windows 10. Created a table "see images", but the "id" which is primary key is not generating any data.
Any idea what to do to fix it so that it generated auto incremented INT? Thanks

[[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is correct. You did not add any record yet. Just click `Apply` in the bottom to persist your changes in the database.

Comment: Do you mean the button with the green tick to the right of "Apply changes"? if so. it did not make the primary key to show any data. please show a photo.